# -[UITableViewCell setDefaultColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1092910e0

Tags: xcode5, tableview, uitableview

This is my first question after always finding answers on here but can't figure this out although I'm sure there is a simple answer to this.

I am trying to implement the MCSwipeTableViewCell into my project but I keep getting an error

> -[UITableViewCell setDefaultColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1092910e0

Forgive me if I'm not properly posting the question.

All I did was add the MCSwipeTableViewCell Pod

Here is my code so far:

MasterViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MCSwipeTableViewCell.h"

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, MCSwipeTableViewCellDelegate>

@property(nonatomic) NSUInteger maximumNumberOfTouches;
@property(nonatomic) NSUInteger minimumNumberOfTouches;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger nbItems;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MCSwipeTableViewCell *cellToDelete;


@end
```

MasterViewController.m

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "MCSwipeTableViewCell.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

static NSUInteger const kMCNumItems = 7;


@interface MasterViewController () <MCSwipeTableViewCellDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate> {

    NSMutableArray *_objects;

}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        _nbItems = kMCNumItems;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundView:backgroundView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _objects.count;
}

-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SectionHeader";
    UITableViewCell *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (headerView == nil){
        [NSException raise:@"headerView == nil.." format:@"No cells with matching CellIdentifier loaded from your storyboard"];
    }

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[headerView viewWithTag:123];
    [label setText:@"Current Contacts"];

    return headerView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 40
    ;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    MCSwipeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[MCSwipeTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        // Remove inset of iOS 7 separators.
        if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        }

        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];

        // Setting the background color of the cell.
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    // Configuring the views and colors.
    UIView *checkView = [self viewWithImageName:@"check"];
    UIColor *greenColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:85.0 / 255.0 green:213.0 / 255.0 blue:80.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];

    UIView *crossView = [self viewWithImageName:@"cross"];
    UIColor *redColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:232.0 / 255.0 green:61.0 / 255.0 blue:14.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];

    UIView *clockView = [self viewWithImageName:@"clock"];
    UIColor *yellowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:254.0 / 255.0 green:217.0 / 255.0 blue:56.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];

    UIView *listView = [self viewWithImageName:@"list"];
    UIColor *brownColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:206.0 / 255.0 green:149.0 / 255.0 blue:98.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];

    // Setting the default inactive state color to the tableView background color.
    [cell setDefaultColor:self.tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor];

    [cell.textLabel setText:@"Switch Mode Cell"];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:@"Swipe to switch"];

    // Adding gestures per state basis.
    [cell setSwipeGestureWithView:checkView color:greenColor mode:MCSwipeTableViewCellModeSwitch state:MCSwipeTableViewCellState1 completionBlock:^(MCSwipeTableViewCell *cell, MCSwipeTableViewCellState state, MCSwipeTableViewCellMode mode) {
        NSLog(@"Did swipe \"Checkmark\" cell");
    }];

    [cell setSwipeGestureWithView:crossView color:redColor mode:MCSwipeTableViewCellModeSwitch state:MCSwipeTableViewCellState2 completionBlock:^(MCSwipeTableViewCell *cell, MCSwipeTableViewCellState state, MCSwipeTableViewCellMode mode) {
        NSLog(@"Did swipe \"Cross\" cell");
    }];

    [cell setSwipeGestureWithView:clockView color:yellowColor mode:MCSwipeTableViewCellModeSwitch state:MCSwipeTableViewCellState3 completionBlock:^(MCSwipeTableViewCell *cell, MCSwipeTableViewCellState state, MCSwipeTableViewCellMode mode) {
        NSLog(@"Did swipe \"Clock\" cell");
    }];

    [cell setSwipeGestureWithView:listView color:brownColor mode:MCSwipeTableViewCellModeSwitch state:MCSwipeTableViewCellState4 completionBlock:^(MCSwipeTableViewCell *cell, MCSwipeTableViewCellState state, MCSwipeTableViewCellMode mode) {
        NSLog(@"Did swipe \"List\" cell");
    }];

    NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `[cell setDefaultColor:self.tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor];` to do??

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue and the solution is pretty trivial. You have to set the custom class for the cell to *MCSwipeTableViewCell*.

Here's a screenshot for references.

[image: Prototype cell custom class]

Comment: or at the very least you have to inherit the MCSwipeTableViewCell class instead of the UITableViewCell class. so try this:

@interface CTTimerTableViewCell : MCSwipeTableViewCell